# The usage of mysql option --unbuffered

Tags: mysql, database

There is a option named "[unbuffered](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_unbuffered)" of mysql client and a very simple line about it, "Flush the buffer after each query.", in mysql manual.

My question is what is its usage?

I try to read mysql source code and it may be the option "flush mysql client log/output buffer after each query", but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior for the db is to buffer your query before outputting any info. If you run an unbiffered query, you are asking mysql to start the output as soo as possible. Theoretically this only stores one row in memory so you can stream huge tables without running out of memory.

Downsides are you cannot run 2 unbuffered queries at the same time. Whereas buffered queries will jjst enqueue the second one, unbuffered statements will throw an error.

Another downside is that you don't know how many rows are left until you end iterating through the redult.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I'm not sure if "mysql --unbuffered" option is the same as "unbuffered query". They may be different concept.

Comment: This is not about buffering in the database, but about buffering the output to the shell.  By using the `--unbuffered` option, you make sure you see the output of the query immediately after it has completed.